# JSZipped SVG not rendering in Safari

Tags: javascript, image, svg, safari, jszip

I am using JSZip to unzip an svg image. as follows

```
var image= zip.files[entry]._data.getContent();
                    var blob = new Blob([image], {
                        type: mimetype
                    });
                    var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

The mime type is set as `"image/svg+xml"` The blob url is being set into the src attribute in an `<img>` tag. This is working in chrome, firefox, but not in Safari. In safari, the image is not rendered. Any idea why this is happening? Also, if we use `<object>` tag, The image is rendered properly. But I can not use `<object`> tag as it is breaking other functionalities. Can you please let me know how can we get it working in `<img>` tag?

Comment: Can you confirm that Safari generates a valid SVG file?

Comment: I have tried unzipping the file manually and then tried rendering it. I used $httpService to get the data at file location. Then created a blob by passing the proper mimetype and then created URL from it. This URL when assigned to the img tag, works perfectly fine. But I can not do unzipping manually.